# L-BFGS Convergence Rate

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization

I can be convinced that BFGS can converge superlinearly, but I haven't been able to find anything reliable regarding L-BFGS. Can L-BFGS converge superlinearly? Are there any instances in which this can be true?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).